# How do I use selectAndWait in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to teach myself how to use Selenium IDE (1.7.2) and I'm running into some trouble.  I have a Javascript form which has two fields that are linked in a hierarchy:

```
Field A: Fruits / Vegetables
Field B:
if Field A is Fruits: Apples / Oranges
if Field B is Vegetables: Broccoli / Corn
```

I tried to record a test like this:

```
select Field A=Fruits
select Field B=Apples
```

However, Field B doesn't load in time and causes the test to fail.

So I tried this:

```
selectAndWait Field A=Fruits
select Field B=Apples
```

However, upon hitting `selectAndWait`, it waits forever and never advances even when Field B has loaded and the value is available to select.

Do I need to set how long to wait for `selectAndWait`?

Comment: Latest Selenium IDE (1.8) is now available now. It is less trouble to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try out this one, Use Pause instead of selectAndWait

```
select field a=fruits
Pause for 5000 MS
then 
Select field B
```